# Flutter, Couldn't get firebase query

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some name data in firebase collection and I am getting new name input in app and adding the data to the same collection in firebase so, I am using an if condition to check if the name already exists in firebase. But the if the condition doesn't work I tried solving it by creating a new function and returning a bool. But didn't work. How do I approach this problem. Is it not the right way to fetch the data from firebase?

```
SaveButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (NameController.text.isEmpty) {
                                  Get.snackbar(
                                      'Error:', "Borrower Name can't be empty",
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.red);
                                } else if (FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                        .collection('lender')
                                        .doc(auth.currentUser!.email)
                                        .collection('borrowers')
                                        .where('Name',
                                            isEqualTo:
                                                NameController.text)
                                        .snapshots()
                                        .isEmpty ==
                                    false) {
                                  Get.snackbar('Error',
                                      'Borrower Name exists, Enter new name',
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.red);
                                }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter, Couldn't get firebase query snapshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72756037/flutter-couldnt-get-firebase-query-snapshots)

Answer (score 1):

.isEmpty return Future, So you have to add await to wait until function completed

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('lender')
.doc(auth.currentUser!.email)
.collection('borrowers')
.where('Name',isEqualTo:NameController.text)
.snapshots()
.isEmpty
```

Comment: I tried but didn't work