# Flutter, Couldn't get firebase query snapshots

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I fetching data from firebase performing a query and updating a bool based on the query. But my code doesn't work. I tried printing the snapshots but I get "Instance of '_ControllerStream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'" in the terminal how do I solve this.

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>namees = await FirebaseFirestore
        .instance
        .collection('lender')
        .doc(auth.currentUser!.email)
        .collection('borrowers')
        .where('Name', isEqualTo: textfieldname).snapshots();
    print(namees);
    if (namees.isEmpty == true) {
      setState(() {
        isThere = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isThere = false;
      });
    }
```

Comment: In case you need to fetch the data only once (and do not listen to a stream), use `get()` https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: I had a similar question before. Please refer to this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72692744/flutter-firebase-query-with-class-and-it-dont-excute-print-function-inside-the), I might give you some hints.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is the expected behavior you would like to see? Do you want to fetch data only once, or listen to the changes in the query? It looks to me like you’d actually like to check if the array of documents has elements, in order to update the state, but it’s not clear. You can refer to [Firestore real time listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) documentation, which shows how to set up the listener with the `listen()` callback method.